# How to find the type of variables in a column in an imported table

Tags: r

Why does typeof output show list instead of num?
I tried instead to write the Class function, add square brackets, change comma positions and it also does not help
lines 23-25

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) but rather both code and error messages in text form.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `typeof`, you should use`class`. To get all of the columns' classes at once, you can do

```r
sapply(starwars, class)
       name      height        mass  hair_color  skin_color   eye_color  birth_year
"character"   "integer"   "numeric" "character" "character" "character"   "numeric" 
        sex      gender   homeworld     species       films    vehicles   starships 
"character" "character" "character" "character"      "list"      "list"      "list"
```